# Should a restaurant website use PDF or HTML for menus for best SEO?

Tags: html, search, optimization, seo, search-engine

I'm trying to create something that will have strong SEO results. I have two options to display the menu's for the restaurant on the website:

1. Use HTML to actually create each menu on the site
2. Link each menu as a downloadable PDF

My main concern is which route will give me better search results. If I use HTML to create the menu's, will this clutter my results with too many key words? (Things like ingredients in each menu item; hamburger, fish, steak etc). On the other hand, is there any benefit for SEO if I go the route to link the menu's as downloadable PDFs?

Comment: It seems like you want complete SEO tutorial. Not only the menus which deside the more SE friendly website. You can go through this as a beginning of SEO http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/en//webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf

Comment: I've asked for this question to be moved to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com where it is a better fit.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the file type preferences of search engines are not programming related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SEO Better results of pdf.**

There are some pros and cons for using pdf because PDF will lead to the long tail keywords, for more competitive short tail keywords. But it is very useful for downloadable and also better SEO.

This link will be helpful you to take right decision:  [pros and cons](http://searchengineland.com/are-pdfs-optimal-for-seo-182076)

If you have the necessary to use pdf. Kindly follow up the below steps.

if you use the content on the pages in PDF-format the pieces of advice below will help you:

**1. Use PDF text files**

Search engines are able to recognize the text. With the pictures it will be less obvious. So make sure that your PDF file contains plain text, not words in the form of pictures. If the document you want to convert to the target page of the site is scanned use special tools to convert a document to text.

**2. Prescribe title**

Search engines pay attention to the ‘title’ tag. You can prescribe it in the document properties. Also in the properties you can assign keywords and information about the author. Experts have not yet agreed whether the last of these properties influence on the rankings, but, at least, there will be no negative impact.

**3. Set the SEO-friendly URL / file name**

Typically the name of the PDF file becomes a part of the URL, so give the document a simple name, which would contain the keywords.

**4. Use standard SEO methods**

Do not forget about standard SEO methods. Place the internal links to PDF pages to give them credibility. Place links from your PDF page to other relevant pages. Do not forget about keywords, images optimization, and content of high quality.

**5. Cut down the size of the file**

The large size of the file will load slower, impacting negatively on the users behavior and ranking. Use special features that will reduce the size of PDF.

**6. Avoid duplicating content**

Availability of HTML and PDF versions of the same content can be useful sometimes, but only if you take action to prevent problems with duplicate content. Remember that you may receive a duplicate, if you re-download PDF, changing the file name and URL.

**7. Do not save the file to read in the latest Acrobat version**

Save PDF files in the old version of Acrobat because many users may not have the latest version of the Reader. It is unlikely that someone will update the program in order to read your page.

**8. Write protection**

Otherwise anyone can upload your file to the site and change it at will (including editing your links).

Summarizing it should be said that despite the fact that the search engines do apprehend PDF pages, webmasters still recommend to use HTML where possible. Users are used to them and feel while working with them more comfortable. In addition, it is easier to add to HTML interactive and social functions. So using of PDF on the site is only appropriate in a few cases:

**You have a lot of PDF pages, which users find valuable;**
Your PDF page is difficult to convert into an equivalent and convenient HTML page;
The site has content meant for print or download (manual, booklet, form to fill out by hand, etc.);
Cost-benefit ratio does not seem reasonable. For example, you have only a few PDF pages and you do not want to waste time or money converting them to HTML.

Answer (score 2):

HTML is better for getting rank instead of using PDF. People generally ignore PDF Url's in search engine.